# Java (14 and above) instanceof cast to generics (e.g. List<String> )

Tags: java, pattern-matching, instanceof, java-17

I'm deserializing JSON payloads using Jackson. I have some fields that can be either Objects or Arrays of Objects. So In my Java code I'm declaring

```
class Outer{
    private Object inner;
}
```

I know that inner can be either `Map<String,String>` or `List<Map<String,String>>`

since I need to do some work with this inner object I have to reside to if - instance of

```
if (inner instanceof List){
    List<Map<String,String>> innerAsList = (List<Map<String,String>>)inner;
    ...
}else if (inner instanceof Map){
    Map<String,String> innerAsMap = (Map<String,String>)inner;
    ...
}else{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("List or Map only");
}
```

Now trying to use the "new" pattern matching for `instanceof` fails to compile (I'm using JDK 17 with previews enabled)

```
if (inner instanceof List<Map<String,String>> innerAsList){
    ...
}else if (inner instanceof Map<String,String> innerAsMap){
    ...
}else{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("List or Map only");
}
```

fails to compile

> `'Object' cannot be safely cast to 'List<String>'`

Using wildcard cast compiles

```
if (inner instanceof List<?> innerAsList){
   ...
}else if (inner instanceof Map<?,?> innerAsMap){
  ...
}else{
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("List or Map only");
}
```

but I then I still need to cast to the correct generic.

Is this solvable somehow? Is it missing functionality?If so are there plans to have it in a future release?

Comment: No. This new pattern cannot be used with unsafe casts. The error message is fairly clear about this too, no? The mindset of team OpenJDK is to not add features unless SURE that it's a good idea, because it's much easier to add something later, than to break code by removing functionality later. This is a corner case that leaves you feeling a bit queasy so, for now, it's not allowed. (My guess is, it'll never be).

Comment: The error is clear, the rationale behind it is not so much: You cannot check if an object is of a generic type (instanceof List<String> will anyway say `'Object' cannot be safely cast to 'List<String>'` but then again you are never sure that a List<String> actually contains Strings.

As stated, it is a corner case, but it cuts the usefulness of the feature in half

Comment: @johnmerm Let me turn this around: what reason did you have to expect that somehow, just because we added a new feature that extends the range of dynamic checking, that a fundamental aspect of how Java generics works (erasure) is somehow magically suspended?  It seems that you mostly fell into a pit of wishful thinking, which is fine, but at least in hindsight, it should be clear that this was wishful thinking, not somehow a "flaw" in pattern matching that requires an explanation.  The explanation is "this is how generics have always worked, and that hasn't changed."

Comment: An `instanceof` check should be thought of as the precondition for safe casting; if `instanceof` says yes, then a cast to the same type is safe (and useful as a value of that type, which excludes null).  If we can't possibly conclude that the cast is safe, we don't let you ask the question, because the answer would not be useful.  (You also can't ask whether a `String` is `instanceof Integer`; the language knows that this isn't a sensible question.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz By now, any Java developer should know that there are no runtime guaranties that an `int` won't end up in a `List<String>` so `instanceof  List<String>` cannot  provide any guarantee and is thus prohibited.
I'm just pointing that since the whole feature is syntactic sugar, in this case, which is not uncommon in the real world, the feature cannot be used
And yes, I'm thinking wishfully, I'm proposing a new feature for a new version, alas in the wrong forum

Answer (score 1):

instanceof is runtime type checking but generics uses type erasure at compile time.
That's why instanceof is not allowed to use for < T > but allowed to use for the raw type List.
You may check out this tutorial about generics cannot use instanceof: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_generics/java_generics_no_instanceof.htm

Alternatively, there are some solutions I can think of.

Approach 1: Check the type of the first list item.

```
if (inner instanceof List && !((List) inner).isEmpty() && ((List) inner).get(0) instanceof Map) {
    // You may continue to check map key and value if necessary.
} else if (inner instanceof Map) {
    // You may continue to check map key and value if necessary.
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("List or Map only");
}
```

Approach 2: Use type casting in try catch block.

```
try {
    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) inner;
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = map.entrySet().iterator().next();
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    System.out.println("Object is not Map<String, String>");
}
```

You can use Approach 2 with Approach 1 to continue to check after instanceof Map.

Approach 3: Use a wrapper class for instanceof.

```
class ListWrapper extends ArrayList<Map<String, String>> { 
    //...
}
```

This way takes you more efforts to implement CRUD operations.

Comment: The question was about if there is a way to use instanceof cast with generics. Obviously there isn't (perhaps a compile extension would help) and as I understand from the comments, there won't be.
Regarding your proposal: 
* Approach 1 would not work for List of more than one items, 
* Approach 2 still requires first to instanceof and then cast and 
* approach 3 won't work with any deserializer (which would eagerly turn anything to List<?> unless instructed otherwise