# why java's new feature "Pattern Matching for instanceof operator" doesn't work on List set or Map without typecasting

Tags: java, java-14

instanceof doesn't work for List even. for example

```
package org.practice;

import java.util.List;

public class InstanceOfDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee emp1 = new Employee(1, "Ram", 10000);
        Employee emp2 = new Employee(2, "Shyam", 20000);
        Employee emp3 = new Employee(3, "Radha", 30000);

        Object obj = List.of(emp1, emp2, emp3);

        if (obj instanceof List empList) {
            for (Employee emp : empList) { //Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Employee
                System.out.println(emp.getId());
                System.out.println(emp.getName());
                System.out.println(emp.getSalary());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in the above code instanceof got true and even declared empList got created but doesn't gives any advantage to the developer because in the for loop empList can't be used without type casting as `for (Employee emp : (List<Employee>)empList)`. And if we are doing type casting only then use type casting on obj itself like traditional code then whats the use of this feature.

Comment: related [Java (14 and above) instanceof cast to generics (e.g. List<String> )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75220488/85421) ? (but you *must* already know it)

Comment: `instanceof` _can't_, and never has been, able to tell the difference between `List<String>` and `List<Employee>`.  The use of this feature is not really for the case of collections or other generic things.

Answer (score 5):

Because it turns it into a raw `List` due to [type erasure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) in [Java Generics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), so you can only get `Object`s out of it.

Since `instanceof` doesn't work with generics (runtime vs. compile-time), you can only get the erased version of any generic class, so any `FooClass<T>` becomes a `FooClass` and you need to do an unchecked cast like in your example.

Comment: Actually, the fact that `obj instanceof List empList` uses a raw type, is responsible for getting a raw type result, not type erasure. Though type erasure is responsible for not allowing to write `obj instanceof List<Employee> empList` here but the OP did not make clear whether this has been tried at all.

Answer (score 4):

Internally, the Compiler does something called Type Erasure:

After the compiler has checked the Types, it converts `List<YourType>` to `List<Object>`. As a result, you cannot check the Types of Collections at runtime. (never ever - there is no direct way around this.)

But you can check the types of objects inside lists. Or you can create Wrapper Classes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a second instanceof pattern match inside the loop:

```
if (obj instanceof List list) {
    for (Object elem : list) {
        if (elem instanceof Employee emp) {
            System.out.println(emp.getId());
            System.out.println(emp.getName());
            System.out.println(emp.getSalary());
        }
    }
}
```

It may be better to use a wildcard instead of a raw type:

```
if (obj instanceof List<?> list)
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"... the for loop empList can't be used without type casting as `for (Employee emp : (List<Employee>)empList)`. And if we are doing type casting only then use type casting on obj itself like traditional code then whats the use of this feature. ..."*

This would be very convenient, I agree.

It's impossible for the compiler to infer the class of the *List* object's *T* type.
You should expect to be *casting* the *[type-parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)* object here.

The *instanceof* keyword is useful for objects, and not any applied *generic-type parameter*.

I would just *cast* the object first; it's a fairly inexpensive operation.

```java
if (obj instanceof List empList) {
    Employee e;
    for (Object emp : empList) {
        e = (Employee) emp;
        System.out.println(e.getId());
        System.out.println(e.getName());
        System.out.println(e.getSalary());
    }
}
```

Output

```
1
Ram
10000
2
Shyam
20000
3
Radha
30000
```

For reference, here is a *Java* documentation on *"instanceof Pattern Matching"*.
*[Pattern Matching for the instanceof Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html)*.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether the cast is “a fairly inexpensive operation”. The cast will happen anyway, regardless of which solution is used. So even if it was a heavily expensive operation, you solution wouldn’t be worse than others, performance-wise.

Comment: @Holger, I mentioned _cost_ because they said the following, _"... And if we are doing type casting only then use type casting on obj itself like traditional code then ..."_,   possibly implying that there shouldn't be more than a single cast.

Comment: That’s very likely the OP’s mindset, but in reality, it doesn’t matter whether you see a single cast or even no cast at all, when `… instanceof List<Employee> empList` worked. Under the hood, there’s still a typecast per element due to type erasure. That’s what I meant with “the cast will happen anyway”. The source code form doesn’t matter. So your code with explicit casts is as efficient as any other variant.